# jpa hibernate @transactional configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Without `@Transactional`, If my web application works, but when it calls a remove I get the following exception:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional
>   EntityManager available

So I'd like to make it transactional, but If I add `@Transactional` to the class or the method, when I run the app I get:

> No qualifying bean of type [net.tirasa.jpaaddressbook.JpaEntryDAO]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency.

My JpaEntryDAO is:

```
@Repository
public class JpaEntryDAO implements EntryDAO {

@PersistenceContext
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;


@Override
@Transactional    // <<<<<<------- add or remove it
public void remove(int id) {
    Entry entry = new Entry();   
    entityManager.remove(id);
}
//[...]
```

The Controller class:

```
@Controller
```

public class AddressBookController {

```
@Autowired
private JpaEntryDAO dao;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" })
public void home() {
}
[...]
```

And the applicationContext.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

  <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />    
  <context:component-scan base-package="net.tirasa.jpaaddressbook/"/>
  <context:annotation-config />

  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

  <!--<bean id="dao" class="net.tirasa.jpaaddressbook.JpaEntryDAO"/>-->

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Rubrica" />
    <property name="username" value="matt3o" />
    <property name="password" value="secret" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/Views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="EntryPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.tirasa.jpdaaddressbook" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <!--org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager-->
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>




  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/> 

</beans>
```

Any ideas to find the error? this is a more complete stacktrace:

```
Error creating bean with name 'addressBookController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.tirasa.jpaaddressbook.JpaEntryDAO net.tirasa.jpaaddressbook.AddressBookController.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.tirasa.jpaaddressbook.JpaEntryDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete stacktrace?

Comment: Program to interfaces not concrete classes. Instead of `JpaEntryDAO` in your controller use `EntryDAO`. (That is the whole point of defining and using an interface that you do not have to know the implementing class).

Comment: Why have you commented the bean of type `JpaEntryDAO` in the xml ?

Comment: can you please share the servlet context xml ?

Comment: thank you @SurajMenon that was the main error.

Comment: @MdC : Glad to be of help. Have posted it as an answer. It would be cool if you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment the bean of type JpaEntryDAO in the xml.